# Azure VM disk expansion online

Tags: azure-vm

Can we expand the disks in Azure VM without stopping the VM itself. (online)

We are looking for an online method to expand the disk which we are not able to crack. We have certain apps moving to IAAS which at times require disk expansion.

Comment: Did you tried [this Article](https://querysurge.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002530951-Azure-Expand-Disk-)

Comment: Thats the known process where you shut down the VM. (offline) We are seacrhing if there is an option to do it online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is you cannot. I tried doing so but you get below message on Azure portal which rules out the possibility

> Disks can be resized or account type changed only when they are unattached or the owner VM is de-allocated.

[image]

So you have to either stop the VM or detach the disk, change its size and attach it again. With VM being online it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks. i really wish they introduce online expansion as Production servers can really suffer because of this.

Comment: May be you could raise a feedback request.